# Django: Sort model based on difference between two of its fields

Tags: django, django-models, annotations

Take a simple class like this.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_viewed  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

All I want to do is sort the output of a query on this model by the time between those two fields so that things that haven't been viewed since they were updated show higher up than things that have.

I feel like I should be able to annotate the table and sort on that annotation, but I'm no genius when it comes to annotations (or raw SQL, for that matter). Could somebody kick me in the right direction?

Comment: was @sdolan solution good enough to pick it after all?

Answer (score 20):

You can do something like this:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'offset': 'last_viewed - last_updated'}).order_by('offset')
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) for a detailed explanation.